# Puppet reboot in stages

Tags: linux, puppet, centos6

I need to do a two step installation of a CentOS6 host with puppet (currently using puppet apply) and got stuck. Not even sure it's currently possible today.

**Step 1**, setup of base system e.g. setup hosts, ntp, mail and some driver stuff.

**reboot required**

**Step 2**, setup of a custom service.

Can this bee done a smooth way? I'm not very familiar with the puppet environment yet.

Comment: unrelated to programming, thus off-topic. Please go to SuperUser and ask there.

Comment: Eh, not quite - this is a question about manifest design, which is in fact programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I very much doubt that any setup steps on a CentOS machine strictly require a reboot. It is usually sufficient to restart the right set of services to make all settings take effect.

Anyway, basic approach to this type of problem could be to

1. Define a custom fact that determines whether a machine is ready to receive the final configuration steps (Step 2 in your question)
2. Protect the pertinent parts of your manifest with an if condition that uses that fact value.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a file first, then delete it when you are done installing the base system (ntp in the below example)

for example

```
exec { '/tmp/reboot':
  path    => "/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin",
  command => 'touch /tmp/reboot',
  onlyif => 'test ! -f /tmp/rebooted',
}


service { 'ntp':
    require => Exec['/tmp/reboot'],
...
}

exec { 'reboot':
    command => "mv /tmp/reboot /tmp/rebooted; reboot",
    path    => "/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin",
    onlyif  => "test -f /tmp/reboot",
    require => Service['ntp'],
    creates => '/tmp/rebooted',
}
```